# Using transferable objects from a Web Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, transferable

I currently have this code to create a Web Worker:

```
w = new Worker("webwork.js");
w.onmessage = function(event) { alert(event.data); }
```

And then the `webwork.js` code for the Web Worker:

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    //var ss=r;  //Causes error because of undefined
    var ss="";
    for(var currProp in event) {
        ss+=("event."+currProp+"="+event[currProp]+"\n");
    }
    postMessage(ss);
}
```

Now I want to transfer a 128-Megabyte `ArrayBuffer` with this code:

```
var r = new ArrayBuffer(1048576*128);
w.postMessage(0, [r]);
```

---

Now that I have supposedly transferred the variable `r`, how do I access it from the Web Worker itself. I have tried `event.r`, just `r`, `self.r` and other things like trying to add a second function argument for the array of `ArrayBuffers`, but nothing works.

How can I access the transferred variable(s) from the Web Worker?

Comment: Won't it be in `event.data`?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. If I use "w.postMessage(0,[r]);", then "event.data" is the 0, but I don't know where the array of ArrayBuffers is located at, even by inspecting all of the properties of the event. I can't find it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
postMesage(aMessage, transferList)
```

In `transferList`, you must specify the transferable objects that are contained in `aMessage`:

```
const objData = {
    strText: "coolcmd",
    objArrayBuffer: new ArrayBuffer(10),
    objTypedArray: new Int8Array(20)
};
objWorker.postMessage(
    objData,
    [objData.objArrayBuffer, objData.objTypedArray.buffer]
);
// The transferred objects are now empty (detached
// from resource). Specifically,
// objData.objArrayBuffer.byteLength returns 0, and
// any access to its content will throw an exception.
```

In the worker:

```
self.onmessage = objEvent => {
    console.log(
        objEvent.data.strText,
        objEvent.data.objArrayBuffer,
        objEvent.data.objTypedArray
    );
};
```

Or using an [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter):

```
self.onmessage = ({data: {strText, objArrayBuffer, objTypedArray}}) => {
    console.log(
        strText,
        objArrayBuffer,
        objTypedArray
    );
};
```

[List](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects#supported_objects) of transferable objects.

Comment: Does anyone know if this tranfers ownership, or makes a copy? I tried it and it looks like it transfers ownership.

Comment: Create ArrayBuffer and Int8Array only once! Then keep sending it back and forth. Otherwise using transferable objects makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Pawel can you elaborate how you can keep sending it back and forth? Once you've received the array, if you try to postMessage it again the browser complains with "ArrayBuffer at index 0 is already neutered."

Comment: @dooderson A bit of a late answer, but for posterity: Yes, this transfers ownership (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable). I assume its to maintain atomicity

Comment: @Tony Your link is broken, this one works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects

Answer (score 89):

The answer given by sbr works, but it would cause a copy of the data to be made before being sent to the worker. That could be slow for a large amount of data. 
To use "transferable objects" you actually transfer the ownership of the object to or from the web worker. It's like passing by reference where a copy isn't made. The difference between it and the normal pass-by-reference is that the side that transferred the data can no longer access it.
I believe the way you should send the data in your example is:

```
w.postMessage(r,[r]);  // first arg is r, not 0 as in the question
```

And the way you would access it in the web worker:

```
addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    var r = event.data;
});
```

---

In my own application I needed to send a large typed Float64Array from the web worker to the main thread, without the performance penalty of the copy. It took lots of trial and error and searching, so I figured I should include that example here for anyone else who gets stuck with a similar problem.
  This is the code that worked on the worker side (arr is my Float64Array):

```
self.postMessage(arr.buffer, [arr.buffer]);
```

On the receiving main thread I have:

```
theWorker.addEventListener('message', function(ev) {
    var arr = new Float64Array(ev.data);  // just cast it to the desired type - no copy made
    // ...
});
```

Note that this works in Chrome, but maybe not most other browsers as of this date (haven't tried yet.)
Also, if you want to send other information in addition to the large array, you can do this:

```
self.postMessage({foo:"foo", bar:arr.buffer}, [arr.buffer]);
```

On the receiving (in this example the main) thread:

```
theWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    var foo = event.data.foo;
    var arr = new Float64Array(event.data.bar);  // cast it to the desired type
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer because it explains the purpose of the second array parameter much better.

Comment: Thanks for actually showing how to send copyable data in addition to transferring the buffer. I couldn't find a decent example on MDN anywhere.

Comment: I also couldn't figure this out based on the MDN docs. I opened https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/23099 about making the documentation a bit clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Try w.postMessage([0,r]). To use transferable objects, one needs to pass the array buffer as the second item on an array. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#communicating-with-a-dedicated-worker)

Comment: It's the second parameter that needs to be passed and that is considered transferable. Your answer is confusing.

Answer (score -5):

this works for me :

//in the Main

```
var x = new ArrayBuffer(1048576*128);
w.postMessage({buffer: x});
```

// In the worker thread, in message handler,

```
processMessage: function(ev){
    var buffer = ev.data.buffer,
    // other stuff . buffer is referenced correctly here. 
}
```

Comment: This will only *clone* the ArrayBuffer; not transfer ownership between threads.